# WordPress with Elementor can't save all sections in single page

Tags: wordpress, xampp, elementor

I am using XAMPP on Windows for the local development of WordPress with Elementor. I am building a site with lectures that need to contain a massive number of sections. I reached a gap of limitations, but this limitation is related to PHP, MySQL or Apache configuration. I already increased the limits of PHP from the php.ini file, but with no results.

I tried when "safe mode" was on - the result was the same.

I already checked the official documentation. There is not any limitation on using sections.

Here are the configurations that I am using now:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the log file located in to the xampp\apache\logs\error.log, I saw the error:
`` WordPress database error Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes for query UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = `` 
After a short research I found that this config can be changed from xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini file
I changed
`max_allowed_packet=1М to max_allowed_packet=100M` and the issue was resolved.